# Firefox and IE continue to load after content has been inserted into a DIV

Tags: javascript, firefox, loading, innerhtml

I have a situation where I'm inserting javascript generated HTML code into a DIV.  One would think this would be a no brainer, but for some reason, once the code is in, the status bar and tab loading graphics start up in both browsers and never stop again.  The page continually appears to be loading data, but in reality, there's nothing more to load.  Any idea why this may be happening?  Solutions?  I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Does it load forever or will it time out eventually?

Comment: It would help to show some code here.  Are you using setInterval anywhere?  Are you calling a function recursively to load the content?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Firebug plug-in for Firefox. Open it up and got to the **NET** tab. That will allow you to see your network activity. Something on the server may be stalling. This will help you find it.